# Quadratic Equations and their roots.

Tags: quadratics

I want to know if there is any way of finding out whether a quadratic equation has ratonal roots or not.

Comment: Well, for the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, as long as $a, b, c$ are all rational, it all comes down to whether $b^2-4ac$ is the square of a rational number or not. I don't think more can be said, really.

Comment: If one considers only the *integer* coefficients quadratic equations, then one has https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Using the quadratic formula, $x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.  This means that you have to check $b^2-4ac$ whether it is a square number to check if the roots are under the square root.